# VBA - The code that I ran does not return the data for the second month

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub UpdateData()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, i As Long, j As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, key As Variant, rows As Collection
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through each row in Sheet1
    For i = 2 To lr1
        key = ws1.Cells(i, "B").Value & "_" & i
        ' Create a new collection for each key
        Set rows = New Collection
        ' Loop through each row in Sheet2 to find matching keys and dates
        For j = 2 To lr2
            If ws2.Cells(j, "A").Value = Split(key, "_")(0) Then
                If CDate(ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value) >= CDate(ws2.Cells(j, "B").Value) And CDate(ws1.Cells(i, "A").Value) <= CDate(ws2.Cells(j, "C").Value) Then
                    rows.Add j
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        ' Store the key and collection in the Dictionary
        dict.Add key, rows
    Next i

    ' Loop through each key in the Dictionary
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Set rows = dict(key)
        ' Loop through each corresponding row in Sheet2 to populate the data in Sheet1
        For Each j In rows
            ws1.Cells(Split(key, "_")(1), "C").Value = ws2.Cells(j, "D").Value
            ws1.Cells(Split(key, "_")(1), "D").Value = ws2.Cells(j, "E").Value
        Next j
    Next key
End Sub
```

I get a report with the data for each month which is in sheet 1, and I have a checlist in sheet 2 having the relevant information for each unique key with the start date and end date. my code has to match the date in sheet 1 if it falls within the start date and end date in sheet and look up for the unique key. In the above code it just loops through the columns and stores the data in a dictionay and returns it. but the repeated keys are ignored and the cells are blank. Can you help me handle this please?

```
My sheet 1 looks like 
Date               Key             Name           Last Name
01.01.2023        ABC10
01.01.2023        HDF87
01.01.2023        DFR98
02.01.2023        ABC10
02.01.2023        ABC10
02.01.2023        HDF87
02.01.2023        DFR98
02.01.2023        ABC10
01.02.2023        ABC10
01.02.2023        HDF87
01.02.2023        DFR98
02.02.2023        ABC10
02.02.2023        ABC10
02.02.2023        HDF87
02.02.2023        DFR98
02.02.2023        ABC10
```

Sheet 2 has

```
Key          Start Date       End Date         Name             Last Name 
ABC10        01.01.2023       31.01.2023       Laptop            Dell
ABC10        02.01.2023       02.01.2023       Mobile            Apple 
ABC10        01.02.2023       01.01.2023       computer        thinkpad
ABC10        02.02.2023       02.01.2023       chair             ikea
HDF87        01.01.2023       31.01.2023       Watch            Apple
DFR98        02.02.2023       02.01.2023       cup              ikea
```

Comment: Start Date and End Date in Sheet 2 don't look very plausible...

Comment: what is the expected result for a Key which is corresponds to 2 lines?  (02.01.2023        ABC10)

Comment: the expected result would have the for 02.02.2023 ABC10 the code should return Mobile and Apple as name and last name in sheet 1 and once the code sees 02.02.2023 ABC10 the expected result would be Chair and ikea as name and last name

Comment: Please check your sheet 2 data. I don't think that they are correct - esp. End Date. What Excel-version do you have? You could achieve the same result with formulas ...

Answer (score 0):

Build the dictionary from Sheet2 first and then use it as lookup for Sheet1.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateData()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lr1 As Long, lr2 As Long, i As Long, j As Variant
    Dim dict As Object, k As Variant, n As Long
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

    lr1 = ws1.Cells(ws1.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lr2 = ws2.Cells(ws2.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Build dictionary from ws2
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With ws2
        For j = 2 To lr2
            ' check valid dates
            If IsDate(.Cells(j, "B")) And IsDate(.Cells(j, "C")) Then
                k = Trim(.Cells(j, "A"))
                If Not dict.exists(k) Then
                   dict.Add k, New Collection
                End If
                ' add to date range and names to collection
                dict(k).Add .Cells(j, "B").Resize(, 4).Value2, CStr(j)
            Else
                MsgBox ws2.Name & " Invalid dates on row " & j, vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next j
    End With
    
    ' update sheet1
    Dim dt As Date, dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, ar
    With ws1
    
        For i = 2 To lr1
            
            ' check valid date
            If Not IsDate(.Cells(i, "A")) Then
                MsgBox ws1.Name & " Invalid date on row " & i, vbExclamation
                Exit Sub
            End If
 
            dt = .Cells(i, "A")
            k = Trim(.Cells(i, "B"))
            'Debug.Print i, k, Format(dt, "dd-mmm-yyyy")
            
            ' loop through date ranges for key
            If dict.exists(k) Then
                For j = 1 To dict(k).Count
                   ar = dict(k)(j)
                   dtStart = ar(1, 1)
                   dtEnd = ar(1, 2)
                   ' check date within range
                   If dt >= dtStart And dt <= dtEnd Then
                        .Cells(i, 3) = ar(1, 3)
                        .Cells(i, 4) = ar(1, 4)
                        n = n + 1
                        Exit For
                   End If
                Next
            End If
           
        Next i
    End With
    
    MsgBox n & " rows out of " & lr1 - 1 & " updated", vbInformation
End Sub
```